# Opening PDF fle

Tags: vb.net

I want to open a pdf file when the user clicks a button. I know that I can do it using the code below.
`Process.Start("C:\Program Files\mypdf.pdf")`

But I want it to be something like the way on how to access files from the Resource folder like this:
`Process.Start(My.Resources.mypdf)`

Answer (score 0):

- Right click on any of the tabs in your toolbox and click choose
  items.(Just make sure you have a version of adobe reader installed
  before starting.)
- When the dialog box pops up click the 'com components' tab then pick
  tha 'adobe pdf reader' com component.
- Click ok and you should now see a 'adobe pdf reader' control in your
  toolbox. Click this and drag it to your vb form.(you may need to
  resize it, usually appears very small).
- Now in order to read any pdf just alter the 'src' property of the
  control either in code or in the designer.
- when you run the program you should be able to view the pdf doc in
  the vb form with most of the options you get in adobe reader. Here is
  how you would alter the 'src' property in code.

**Code:**

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    AdobeReader.src = "C:\mydoc.pdf"

End Sub
```

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c165c82d-ac79-477e-abab-3efd330d149f/how-to-open-pdf-file-in-vbnet-applicatin?forum=vbgeneral)

Comment: what if I deploy my project and run it on different PC, do you think the doc.pdf will still run?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't unless they have adobe uninstalled, but that's why you use the component and make sure your PDF is there when you compile.